# How to set row.names=FALSE and na=" " by default for write.csv?

Tags: r, dataframe

While I issue the `write.csv(dataframe_name,"File_name.csv")`, I add the parameters `row.names=F` and `na=" "` for ease of reading in MS-Excel. Is there a default option in R to always set these parameters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can easily write a function to mask this

```
write.csv <- function(...,row.names=FALSE,na = ' '){
   utils::write.csv(..., row.names = row.names, na = na)
}
```

and place this in your `.Rprofile` file [or build a simple package which exports this....]

Comment: Until three months down the track and the non-standard defaults start causing grief... but yes, +1. Buyer beware :-)

Comment: ideally you would name your function differently so it would be distinct from write.csv. If you have many such functions, it's better to put them in a package

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the write.table function

```
write.table( dataframe_name, filename = "file.csv, sep=",", row.names=FALSE, ...)
```

That's worked for me at least.